# To get the active javascript functions of a webpage as soon as we open

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to print the function calls which are made to the web browser from the webpage i.e the active functions of a javascript. But my approach is not correct i guess because with the help of the below code I m getting all the javascript functions.

```
function tracecalls(par) {
    var f, fname;
    for (fname in window) {
        f = window[fname];
        if (typeof fun === 'function') {
            window[fname] = (function(fname, fun) {
                var arg = arguments;
                return function() {
                    return par.apply(this, arg);
                    f.apply(this, arg);
                }
            })(fname, f);
        }
    }
}
tracecalls(function(fname, f) {
    console.log("Function Name : " + fname);
});
```

After going through some articles I came to know that, we can get the active function i.e the names of the functions which are invoked dynamically with the help of Ecmascript 6 Proxy. As I am completely new to this can anyone guide me on how to proceed with the proxies..

Comment: What is `f`? What is `par`? Why do you capture the `arguments` of that IIFE instead of those of the new function?

Comment: function tracecalls(par) 
{
   var f,fname;
   for (fname in window) 
   {
      f = window[fname];
      if (typeof fun === 'function') 
      {
            window[fname] = (function(fname, fun) {
            var arg = arguments;
              return function() 
               {
                  return par.apply(this, arg);
                  f.apply(this, arg);
               }
           })(fname, f);
     }
    }
}
tracecalls(function(fname, f) 
{
           console.log("Function Name : " + fname);    
});

Comment: the above one is the code I got. Now I want to use the concept of Ecmascript 6 proxy to accomplish my task. I need help with this implementation part..

Comment: I can't quite tell what your expectations are, but it's entirely possible that functions that exist could hidden in a scope that is inaccessible to other JavaScript. Do you expect to get _all_ functions, or all _global_ functions?

Comment: I only need the active functions not all functions. They all are hidden  in a scope. But I only want the active functions i. e the function calls which are made to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is actually correct, you've just made some mistakes in the implementation.

Do not try to use a proxy here, which is much more complicated - and you cannot swap out the global object for a proxified version of itself anyway.

```
function tracecalls(par) {
    for (var name in window) {
        if (typeof window[name] === 'function') {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ there is no variable `fun` anywhere
            window[name] = (function(fname, f) {
//                                          ^ don't use `fun` here
//              you don't need `var arg = arguments;` here
                return function() {
                    par(fname);
//                  ^   ^^^^^ you don't need apply, just pass the name
//                  ^ no return here
                    return f.apply(this, arguments);
//                  ^^^^^^ yield result  ^^^^^^^^^ pass through current arguments, not `arg`
                }
            }(name, window[name]));
        }
    }
}
tracecalls(function(fname) {
    console.log("Function Name : " + fname);
});
```

Comment: But the problem with this code is all the javascript functions are in arguments. When I tried to print the console.log(argument);  above "return function() {"  I can see all the functions prior to load the page. So, the best method is to use the proxy to capture the function calls made to the browser.

Comment: @Sunil: As I understood, you want to get the logs when the respective functions are called not when the page is loaded, so you are not supposed to put a `console.log` above the `return function() { …`?

Comment: @Sunil: As I said, you cannot use a proxy to capture accesses on the global object.